# cannot load Java class kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator

Tags: java, ruby, rubygems, rvm, jruby

Im using the following gem
https://github.com/joekiller/jruby-kafka

I have java installed:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

and using

```
jruby-1.7.19
```

After a succefull `bundle install` I have the following error when trying to execute my app

```
NameError: cannot load Java class kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator
for_name at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaClass.java:1286
get_proxy_class at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:34
java_import at file:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.19/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:27
map at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2412
java_import at file:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.19/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/java/core_ext/object.rb:22
Consumer at /home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/jruby-kafka-1.4.0-java/lib/jruby-kafka/consumer.rb:6
(root) at /home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/jruby-kafka-1.4.0-java/lib/jruby-kafka/consumer.rb:5
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1071
require at /home/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.19/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69
(root) at /home/user/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.19/gems/jruby-kafka-1.4.0-java/lib/jruby-kafka.rb:1
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1071
require at /home/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.19/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128
require at /home/user/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.19/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121
(root) at app.rb:4
```

This is done in ubuntu 14.04.
The app works as it should -no errors- when installed to other systems with same setup (os, jvm, rvm, jruby version). I'm suspecting that this has something to do with the paths of the jar files themselves.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved when I removed jruby at all and reinstall by also stating the ruby.

```
rvm install jruby --1.9
```

This time the gem was installed along with the jar dependencies.